# Bootstrap popover not showing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to get the bootstrap popover to work on a website and I have been somewhat successful. I can get the popover to show up when the link is clicked however I don't see any content in the box except for the title. I have tried it 2 ways:

```
<a class="btn btn-link login-popover" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Sign in to the website builder" data-html="true" data-content="Lo4545445"> Sign in  <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

and

```
$('.login-popover').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'Sign in to the website builder',
    content: 'testing 123',
    trigger: 'click'
});
```

However neither one actually shows the content in the box. You can see what I mean by going to http://www.onemobi.net/new and clicking `Sign in` at the top.

**Edit:** I'm not doing both of these at the same time. I tried one and then the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must place the code in a function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login-popover').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'Sign in to the website builder',
    content: 'testing 123',
    trigger: 'click'
  });
});
```

or

```
$(function () { 
   $(".login-popover").popover();    
});
```

then it works. But why are you defining the popover settings twice (both in script and as data attributes)?

**Eureka!**

It seems that you have changed the default styling in bootstrap.css. The content of the popover IS actually shown, in a `<p>`, but you have

```
.btn-group {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

obvious, by changing font-size: 0; the content will be visible (tested in chrome inspector) Add to your CSS

```
.btn-group {
  font-size: 12px; /*or whatever size */
}
```

Comment: I tried one and then the other not both at the same time. Wrapping the code in $(document).ready() just makes it not work at all.

Comment: Actually its still doing the same thing.

Comment: Has updated the answer, somehow misleading. Well, you must have an error somewhere else in your code - do you get any errors in the console? I took your code, pastet it, wrapped the script in a function and it works.

Comment: No errors on the console. The popover shows up its just the testing 123 part doesn't.

Comment: .btn-group is responsible for the content is not being visible

Comment: Have I told you how awesome you are? Well You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

As I checked the current version (v2.2.2) this bug had been resolved. Please download the latest one.

Comment: Can you expand you're answer? do you mean Bootstrap version?